# jquery .clone() values for radio buttons and text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this can be done because I was reading up on it. But, I can't get mine to work. At the minute my inputs all clone which is all good. However this is the crucial part. I need to keep all the checked radio buttons etc currently. It just acts, as if it is brand new and has not been filled. I am not quite sure how to achieve. This my code is below. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
var k = jQuery('.c_questions');
for(var j = 0; j < k.length; j++ ){
    var storeAll = jQuery(k[j]);
    jQuery(storeAll).clone().appendTo('.payment');
}
```

Comment: Post your `html` too

Comment: What is `jQuery(storeAll)` supposed to do? `storeAll` already has a jQuery set in it.

Comment: it just contains all the inputs

Comment: @JacobKenyon: But that's what `storeAll` contains.

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` state of form controls are not part of the DOM (this is also true of `selected` and the *current* rather than default `value`), so cloning doesn't copy them. But the good news is you can copy them yourself by looping through the clones and setting their `checked` state to match the original's `checked` state:

```
var k = jQuery('.c_questions');
for (var j = 0; j < k.length; j++ ){
    var storeAll = jQuery(k[j]);
    var originals = jQuery(storeAll); // See comment on question, this call is suspect
    var clones = originals.clone();
    var cloneRadios = clones.find("input[type=radio]");
    originals.find("input[type=radio]").each(function(index) {
        cloneRadios.eq(index).prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
    clones.appendTo('.payment');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that you don't realise how relieved I am now with this, this was the final hurdle I had to overcome, so now I can just do this for the text area ones too etc..

Comment: @JacobKenyon: No worries. The above can be simplified depending on the DOM structure, so it would be useful for you to post the HTML as Guruprasad suggested.

Comment: Not as simple as just posting the html it's all in php, but still none the less, problem solved.